# React.CreateElement issue on react-router-v4, not v4-alpha4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out why a specific function is working with the alpha version of React Router but not the current v4 version

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Match } from 'react-router';

import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

render(<Root />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rbm-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.17.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**NotFound.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class NotFound extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
    )
  }
}

export default NotFound;
```

When i switch the react-router version from 4.0.0-alpha.4 to ^4.0.0, i get the following errors

[image]

I don't have an issue using the alpha version, however I would like to figure out what the issue is so i can learn from it.  Also if needed i can push the code to github if anyone wants to look at it locally.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Match` isn't a thing anymore. Change `Match pattern` to `Route path` and you should be good. Also, import everything from `react-router-dom` not `react-router`.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick thanks!  Although, any reason why react-router-dom over react-router?

Comment: Use DOM if you're on the web. Use Native if you're on React Native. You should never use just react-router. The DOM and Native package will ship everything you need.